# What error codes can occur with CopyFileEx?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing some C++ code that needs to call the CopyFileEx function.  The documentation for CopyFileEx, like most other WIN32 functions, says:

*If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.*

Which is all well and good - however does anyone know where I can find a list of the error codes that a specific API function may return via GetLastError?  In this case I want to handle different error conditions in different ways but without a list of the error codes **for this function** I'm going to be reduced to generating the error conditions I want to handle just to see what error code is prodcued or going through the system error codes from numbers 0 to 15999 trying to guess which ones might apply!

Edit: Here is a little more context to help explain the issue and why I want to know if there is a definitive list of error codes that can be returned by a function anywhere.

The code will be used as part of a Windows service so while there are users they won't always be there to respond to errors.  I need to be able to distinguish between errors that don't need reporting every time, if a file is locked I'm just to re-try it again later. If I don't have permissions to read a particular file I can log the problem and carry on, if the destination directory is unreadable or is full then I want the service to stop and to trigger a reporting process that will atrract the attention of a user.

Without a comprehensive list of the ways that CopyFileEx can fail I'm finding it hard to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't give a list of all error codes an API might return for the simple reason that the list may change over time and various implementations of Windows, installed drivers or simple oversight (APIs often return errors caused by other APIs called within the one you called).

Sometimes the docs call out specific errors that are of particular interest for users of that API, but in general they will not has a definitive complete list of errors. Nor should they, which is unfortunate, but is a fact of life.

I sympathize with your plight - there are many times I would have liked this kind of information so I could have a better idea of how to handle problems that should be  anticipated - particularly those that have a reasonable recovery path.  Usually I try to deal with this by testing to find the failure behavior of the APIs, and I'd like to avoid that because it's a pain and it doesn't help much with ensuring that I've covered all the scenarios or against future differences.

However, covering all the scenarios (with a comprehensive list of error codes) or protecting against future changes is really an impossible goal. Consider how Microsoft might have to manage documenting all possble error codes in Win32:

Say the Win32 API has only 2 functions: `foo()` and `bar()`.  `foo()` might generate its own error, `ERROR_FOO` and `bar()` might generate its own error, `ERROR_BAR`.  However, `foo()` calls `bar()`, so `foo()` might also return `ERROR_BAR` if its call to `bar()` returns that error.

The docs reflect the following:

- `foo()` may retun either `ERROR_FOO` or `ERROR_BAR`
- `bar()` may return `ERROR_BAR`

Now, when API v2 is released, `bar()` has been extended to also return `ERROR_BAZ`. for something the size of this API it's simple to manage that the docs for bar() need to be updated to add the new error code (however, note that for an API as large as the real Win32 and an organization as large as MS, the same might not be true, but lets assume it is).

However, the guy adding the new error to `bar()` has no direct visibility to the fact the `foo()`'s behavior has also changed in terms of what errors it might return.  In an API small as this, it's probably not a big deal - in something like Win32 it would be a mess.  Now throw in the fact that Win32 can be dependant on 3rd party code (drivers, plug-ins, COM objects, etc) and the task is now pretty near impossible.

Actually that's not necessarily a great example, since if the error codes were part of the contract of an API `ERROR_BAZ` should have never come into the picture.

So here's another scenario:  the API has an `OpenObject()` function that can return `ERROR_NO_MEMORY` or `ERROR_NOT_FOUND`. When this system was first developed, it had no concept of security (say like MS-DOS), but a new release adds access controls. Now we'd like `OpenObject()` to be able to return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, but it can't because that would change the contract, so a new API `OpenObjectEx()` is added to deal with that situation. There are at least 2 problems here:

- You'll get an explosion of APIs over time that really add little or no value over the old APIs
- what should happen to a legacy application that calls the old `OpenObject()` API and fails because of access restrictions? Neither of the contracted error returns would tell the truth about what the problem is.

This problem is one of the reasons that exception specifications (in C++ or Java) are considered by many to have been a bad idea.

Comment: I understand what you saying; but I just think it's lazyness on Microsofts part. I've always considered the error codes from a function to be almost as much a part of the function definition as the meaning of the parameters it takes;  it's something which if it's changed can break working code.

Comment: I've updated my answer to give an example of why this probably shouldn't be considered lazyness on MS's part.

Comment: Still not convined here :-)  If (and I have) I was writing a library for a 3rd party to use and I said; these functions return some errors but I'm not going to tell you what they are I'd expect my customer to less than pleased.  For the WIN32 API it would not be a trivial task - however as it's the basis for a significant proportion of the worlds code it might be nice if the largest software company in existance made the effort.

Comment: well, it's certainly not a hard and fast thing (for example, many very knowlegable people disagree about exception specifications), but I'd be willing to bet that these are the kinds of things that MS would cite as a rationale. For example, MS has a big problem just with people relying on undocumented behaviors not changing - documenting a more or less unchangable set of errors would really hamper their ability to update the system (even if just to fix bugs).

Comment: Conversely, Linux *does* seem to document the list of error codes certain system calls or system call wrappers may return ([example](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open)).  It's informative and helpful, but as Michael pointed out, it's fragile.

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of [Windows error codes here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(VS.85).aspx) but it doesn't specify the errorcodes per API call. Still, the MSDN site does provide a lot of useful information about most API methods, including the possible error codes they could return.

The [FormatMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(VS.85).aspx) function can be used to translate an error to the proper error message, taking the current Windows language into account. Often, displaying such an error message should be enough. You'd only want to add logic for errors that you might expect and even then you'd just want to show an error message.

When reading about [CopyFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363852(VS.85).aspx), you will read the following beyond the part about getting the GetLastError() call:

> **Remarks**
>
> This function fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED if the destination file already exists and has the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY attribute set.
>
> When encrypted files are copied using CopyFileEx, the function attempts to encrypt the destination file with the keys used in the encryption of the source file. If this cannot be done, this function attempts to encrypt the destination file with default keys. If both of these methods cannot be done, CopyFileEx fails with an ERROR_ENCRYPTION_FAILED error code. If you want CopyFileEx to complete the copy operation even if the destination file cannot be encrypted, include the COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION as the value of the dwCopyFlags parameter in your call to CopyFileEx.

Basically, those are the errors you could normally expect. All others should just result in an error message to the user.

(And I hate it when this site translates the *underscores* to something else...)

Comment: In this case I do need to do a bit more than just display an error. The program needs to take different actions but not knowing which errors the function can generate makes it hard to know how it can fail and what recovery actions I might need to take.

Comment: The Remarks section does list 2 errors that the function might return; but I don't think it is a comprehensive list of errors.  I can think of many other errors that could occurr, no source file, no space on the destination, source file is locked, source is open in another process, no permission to write to target directory... A comprehensive error list for this function is really what I'm after.

Comment: When a file is locked or open or if there's not enough disk space, there will always be a need to tell the user about the problem, since only the user could solve it. Still, error codes in the range of 0 to 499 are related to the file system and some more possible errors. These would be the most important errors in case op copying files.

Answer (score 1):

CopyFileEx is eventually handled by a chain of device drivers, some are written by Microsoft and some might be not, and the device driver returns an arbitrary NTSTATUS code which is translated into a Win32 error code. Since it can be a custom driver returning this NTSTATUS, Microsoft cannot guarantee you anything about it.

The only way CopyFileEx could give you a "short and sweet" list would be if CopyFileEx has changed the verbose error codes into some simple ones -- i.e. it would either return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION or ERROR_GEN_FAILURE for all other errors (i.e. it would **hide** all other errors behind a cryptic error code). We wouldn't want that, wouldn't we?

**Update:** To speak in terms of contract, the user code SHOULD handle CopyFileEx failure (i.e. when it returns FALSE). The user code MAY handle zero or more specific error codes by querying GetLastError upon failure.

It is rare for user code to actually handle error codes. Trying to handle all of them is certainly not the best practice. If a user code has something specific to do for a specific error code, it should do so. Otherwise, the only thing to do with an error code is to indicate it to the user or log it (see FormatMessage) while otherwise treating it as an opaque value.

As I said, the best practice says you SHOULD handle the failure itself -- thus, rollback changes you might've made, memory allocations etc. Things like 'finally' clauses and C++ RAII can help greatly here.

Comment: I'd always expect the operating system API to protect me from having to worry about which device driver eventually writes to disk! If it does not do this then my code could break just because I ran it on a different vendors hardware and that implemention of a driver decided to return a different code.  I'm afraid I'm still sticking to my original point; the error codes an API function can generate are an equally important part of the contract between the API developer and its users as the paramters that the function takes and the type of the value that it returns.

Comment: Wait, did you ask a genuine question or do you use Stack Overflow to propose changes to Windows? If it's the latter, I think there are more appropriate channels with Microsoft :-)

Comment: Firstly of course I was asking a genuine question, as as you can see have accepted (some time ago) the answer from Michael Burr. I didn't like the answer but it did resolve the question I had asked.

Comment: As for your second point on how my code MAY want to handle specic error conditions as reported by GetLastError; all you've done is point out my problem again! I wanted to handle a small number of well defined error cases, disk full for example, how do I work out what error code I'll get from CopyFileEx?  It doesn't tell me, I can go through all 15999 system error codes and try and guess or I can generate the error manually and see -not always easy!

Comment: This looks like the documentation you're looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199(v=PROT.10).aspx -- and yes, there are no promises CopyFileEx won't spew an entirely unknown error code (e.g. when the file is delivered over a not-yet-invented protocol) but you don't have something specific to do for it anyway.